# Eloquent save many to many relation without duplicates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and have a many to many relationship between *products* and *tags*, with a pivot table that has `product_id` and `tag_id` as the only two columns.

My models look as follow:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Tag' );
    }
    // other code
}
```

and

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function product ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Product' );
    }

    protected $fillable = [ 'slug' ];
}
```

The tags table has `id`, `slug` and the timestamps columns. I am trying to assign tags that I'm getting from a form in a comma separated string to a product with the code below:

```php
$tags_r = explode( ',', $request->tags );

$tags = [];

foreach ( $tags_r as $tag ) {
    $tags[] = new Tag( [ 'slug' => strtolower( trim( $tag ) ) ] );
}

$p->tags()->saveMany( $tags );
```

My problem is that when I try to save the tags with no constraint on the `tags.slug` column, I end up with duplicate tags on several rows. When I set the `slug` column to unique to avoid duplicates the code throws an error complaining about the constraint.
How do I make it so that if a tag exists, it is assigned to a product by use of the pivot table and it is only added as a new row in the *tags* table if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: You should use Sync() method for save relational model. check details here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`firstOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods) to avoid adding already existing tags into the database.

```php
foreach ( $tags_r as $tag ) {
    $tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['slug' => str_slug($tag)]);
}

$p->tags()->saveMany( $tags );
```

I also used [`str_slug()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug) instead of manually creating the slug.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `str_slug` seems like a no-brainer bt for some reason, I wanted to keep the spaces instead of replacing them with dashes. I'm ok with dashes though

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you found this answer useful and it helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The code was still refusing to work. It was throwing the same error. I then used `findOrCreate()` and it worked. Maybe you can edit your answer and I'll accept it. The second line of the first chunk of code becomes:
    `$tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['slug' => str_slug($tag)])->id;`
Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the tag already exists it will throw the same error. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Actually, I think all you need to do is use `firstOrCreate()` and you can keep using `saveMany()` like you did in the first place.